# Use Django signal when data is inserted into database from Scrapy

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I would like to integrate Scrapy with Django.

When I insert data into DB from Scrapy, Django signal is not working.

This is the code snippet that is used for signal.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Page)
def create_page(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print('========== page created')
```

This is `pipeline.py` that is used to insert data into DB.

```
class CrawlerPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, unique_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.unique_id = unique_id

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            unique_id=crawler.settings.get('unique_id'),
        )

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        pass

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        site = Site.objects.get(id=self.unique_id)
        page = Page(url=item['url'], site=site)
        page.save()
        return item
```

As you can see, data is inserted into DB on the Scrapy part and it works.

But Django signal is not working as I expected.

I am not sure how I can get *Django signal* to work.

Comment: where is your signal defined, and what does your `apps.py` file look like?